# how stream theora topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I performing a teleoperating experiment via webcam vision and using the wireless channel to transport the date, so i am interested on using the theora data compression.

Using usb_cam_node, rostopic list command  shows me the topic /usb_cam/image_raw/ and /usb_cam/image_raw/theora etc.

Using the the command:

rosrun image_view image_view image:/usb_cam/image_raw/, video is streaming but I am not able to undestand how view  the theora topic: /usb_cam/image_raw/theora .

Anyone could help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34485/how-stream-theora--topic/) by [doxsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2422/doxsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw _image_transport:=theora

---

Originally posted by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) with karma: 341 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2